# What logs or diagnostic steps can I take to check for Debian Jessie network failing to start?

Tags: debian, networking

The network of a Debian Jessie VirtualBox VM I created recently fails to start at runtime. The only way I can get it the network to run properly is by adding `service networking restart` to `/etc/rc.local` or running it manually after logging in which will not work if it is run remotely.

UPDATE: Additional Info.

The first network adapter is configured as `NAT` in Virtual box. The second one is configured as `Bridged Adapter` so it is like an additional computer on the host computer's subnet. The first one is able to connect to the network at boot time and connect to the Internet, but not to machines on the LAN. It s only after running `service networking restart` that the second adapter begins to connect to LAM IPs and is also visible to the other systems on the network.

This the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration. It is a stock Debian Jessie desktop configuration.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.22
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Is there some kind of upstart or systemd init configuration that might be faiing? It is a server based installation so I don't think some desktop related utility might be interfering.

What steps can I take to ensure that the network is actually configured and/or at boot time? The fact starting the networking service in `/etc/rc.local` makes it work lead me to believe it may be simple. What are the scripts run by Debian Jessie at boot time which are the equivalent of `service networking restart`?

Answer (score 2):

Debian has recently switched to using network-manager as the default way of configuring network interfaces. Either configure the network using network-manager or make sure that /etc/init.d/networking gets called in the init startup sequence otherwise the contents of /etc/network/interfaces will be irrelevant.

Run `ls -l /etc/rc[1-5].d/ | grep net` and make sure you see something like the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  25 Oct  2  2014 S01networking -> ../init.d/networking
```

If that checks out, take a look at `dmesg | grep eth0` but replace eth0 with the name of the network adapter on the Virtual Machine. Report eny errors.

If you don't see the networking init script being referenced, or if you see network-manager instead then do the following as root:

```
update-rc.d networking defaults
update-rc.d -f network-manager remove
```

which should install the proper symbolic links in `/etc/rc[1-6].d/` and disable network-manager.

To manually install the symbolic link you can tell it to start in any run level 1-5. For example:

```
pushd /etc/rc1.d/ && ln -s ../init.d/networking S08networking && popd
for i in `seq 2 5` ; do push /etc/rc$i.d/ && ln -s ../init.d/networking S01networking && popd ; done
pushd /etc/rc6.d/ && ln -s ../init.d/networking K07networking && popd
pushd /etc/rc0.d/ && ln -s ../init.d/networking K07networking && popd
```

To manually disable network-manager do:

```
rm /etc/rc*.d/S*network-manager
```

Comment: There was no string matching `net` in the rc.X list, but after following your suggestion this is what came up after searching `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Dec 30 05:08 K07networking -> ../init.d/networking` under rc.6, but that seems to be for stopping the network when the machine shuts down. Have the defaults for `update-rc.d networking defaults` changed in Debian 8?

Comment: The defaults are set in the init script itself. Look at the top of `/etc/init.d/networking`, the default run level is should be set to `S` which corresponds to starting in `/etc/rc1.d/` or "single user" mode. If there is no corresponding symlink in `/etc/rc1.d/` then you can put one there manually, or use `update-rc.d`.